# Excel SUM parts of a string

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sum

in Excel I have a few cells containing numbers separated by a dash, like:

[image: Example]

I use a formula like

```
=TRIM(TEXTBEFORE(G30:G40;"/";1))
```

In the end I would like to sum the three parts seperately so the end result would be something like "12 / 43 / 0".

Though the question was not complete, luckly it was understood what I tried to accomplish.

Comment: Your formula would probably work for the first values, but you need to convert them to number `=sum(--(TEKSTBEFORE(G30:G40;"/";1)))` not sure if `TEKSTBEFORE` is correctly spelled with `KS` or that it should be `X`, but followed your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(A1," / "))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=MAP(A1:A7,LAMBDA(φ, SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(φ," / "))))
```

---

Edit: As OP Commented:

> *Sorry, I think I'm not clear enough. I have to sum all first values,*
> *all second values and all thirth values separately. In this example*
> *the result would be 4 / 98 / 0. That would be the end result. Thanks*
> *for the reply b.t.w*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(" / ",,BYCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" / "&A1:A7," / ",{1,2,3})," / "),LAMBDA(α, SUM(--α))))
```

---

Also in **`Excel Beta` Version you can use <kbd>GROUPBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(,--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" / "&A1:A9," / ",{1,2,3})," / "),SUM)
```

---

Or using <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=PIVOTBY(,,--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" / "&A1:A9," / ",{1,2,3})," / "),SUM)
```

---

To know more on the New Launched function in `Beta Versions` of **`Windows Excel & Mac`** can be found here:

- <kbd>GROUPBY()</kbd> --> **[MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/groupby-function-5e08ae8c-6800-4b72-b623-c41773611505?)** Documentations
- <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd> --> **[MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pivotby-function-de86516a-90ad-4ced-8522-3a25fac389cf?)** Documentations

---

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not clear enough. I have to sum all first values, all second values and all thirth values separately. In this example the result would be 4 / 98 / 0. That would be the end result. Thanks for the reply b.t.w.

Comment: @Stephan use this formula: `=TEXTJOIN(" / ",,BYCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" / "&A1:A7," / ",{1,2,3})," / "),LAMBDA(α, SUM(--α))))`

Comment: @Stephan refer the edit. This one single formula.

Comment: Hi @Mayukh, great work. I already used you previous formula. And will have a look at this one two. I don't want to just copy it, I also want to understand it. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I think the most straigtforward/intuitive would be to use `BYCOL()` here even though I love the use of `GROUPBY()`, it just add redundant parameters.

Comment: @JvdV Sir agree. Only one though!

Answer (score 1):

In BETA version of Excel:
`=BYCOL(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("/"&A1:A10,"/",SEQUENCE(,3)),"/"),SUM)`

[image]

Else:
`=MAP(SEQUENCE(,3),LAMBDA(a,SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("/"&A1:A10,"/",a),"/"))))`

Or if you use Excel 2021 without access to LAMBDA:
`=MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(A1:A10),,0),--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("/"&A1:A10,"/",SEQUENCE(,3)),"/"))`

Comment: I got that update on using single formula with `BYCOL()` or `BYROW()` or `SCAN()` from JvdV Sir!

Comment: Yeah, that means shorter and shorter formulas.

Comment: I haven't got is working yet, using BYCOL. But I will give it an other try later. I was already able to use the solution Mayukh provided. Thank you so much for all the input/information.

Comment: As posted my BYCOL solution is currently only working if you're on the Beta Chanel (pre release of functionality). For current version we need to include LAMBDA:
`=BYCOL(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("/"&A1:A10,"/",SEQUENCE(,3)),"/"),LAMBDA(b,SUM(b))`